# What programming language is it when I write a batch file, and who compiles it?

Tags: batch-file

When I write my .bat file in notepad, what programming language am I really using and who's there to run it and compile it?

Comment: It's interpreted, not compiled, by the, appropriately named, "command interpreter" AKA "DOS command-line" AKA "cmd.exe".

Comment: I don't know if `.bat` files has "official" programming language name. Often they are referred as `windows scripts`,`batch scripts` ...

Comment: The language is the one used specified by whatever shell you use. Bash has its own language, `Powershell` has a different one. `.bat` doesn't really exist - it's the extension used for *DOS* batch files. Windows no longer has a DOS subsystem. Windows batch files use the `.cmd` extension and have additional commands. `.bat` files are *probably* treated the same as `.cmd` files simply because there's no `DOS` shell.

Comment: For example, `pushd` and `popd` can be used to push and pop directory locations in Windows. These commands were *never* available in DOS batches. If you use them in `.bat` files it's because they are treated the same as `.cmd` files

Answer (score 6):

It's a Batch script.

This is its own thing, that has its roots in DOS.

Nobody "compiles" a Batch script; `cmd.exe` interprets your code.

You can [read more on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file).

Answer (score 1):

It's the MS Windows Batch language. It's interpreted, not compiled